# Image Button getting larger one to the screen...?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android application in eclipse....
When I'm trying to put an image button in XML file... it become large one to the screen... 
I tried to adjust the width and height(ex: 50dp and 50dp), But its cropping the image...
What to do....???(the code below is fake one don't mind it,plz...)

```
<Button android:id="@+id/categorybutton"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            style="@style/CategoryButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: Could you translate `it become large one to the screen` to English?

Comment: I mean, that the image button I have placed in layout screen is becoming larger one on the screen...

Comment: But what does `is becoming larger one` mean?

Answer (score 1):

please, remove:

> android:layout_weight="50dp"

...

Comment: @Akhilian There's less use in maintaining that meaningless line. A weight set to dps... why?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:src"@drawable/button_bg"`

Remove `android:layout_weight="50dp"`and set value of `android:layout_height` to `"wrap_content"`

Answer (score -1):

Here's the correct way to format that View, assuming the parent is a LinearLayout with orientation:"vertical", weightSum="100", and you want the button to fill half the parent.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/categorybutton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_dimen"
        style="@style/CategoryButtonStyle"/>
```

Do yourself a favor and store your dimensions in dimens.xml. It will save you a lot of time in the future. Also, weight is not in pixels, so take out the dp. We've set the height to 0dp so the button fills the entire allocated weight.

Comment: `weightSum` is **optional**. Android calculates it automatically.

Comment: I was assuming there was some context to the View OP posted. Either way, the dp cannot be in there.

Comment: That's obvious. And that's obvious too.